# How to collapse the width of CSS-grid to center it in the grid-container

Tags: css, centering, css-grid

Is it possible to collapse the width of a CSS grid with auto-filled columns to the minimal width required to have equal width columns that are centered with respect to the grid container?

IE if I have grid defined like this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
```

and the grid-container is 800px wide, is there a way to ensure the grid itself is only 600px wide instead of 800px?

Since I'm not sure how to explain it properly I've made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mhozx4ns/10/

I'm looking for a way that makes the top container behave like the bottom one if it is wider than what is required to place all children in one row.

```css
body {
  width: 800px;
  background: black;
}

.grid div {
  height: 50px;
  background: #ededed;
}

.css {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 64px;
  grid-row-gap: 64px;
  background: red;
}

.manual {
  width: 664px;
  margin: 32px auto 0;
  background: blue;
}

.manual:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.manual.grid div {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

.manual.grid div:nth-of-type(even) {
  margin-left: 64px;
}

.manual.grid div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="css grid">
  <div>

  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="manual grid">
  <div>

  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `minmax(300px, 1fr)` in your rule, you're saying this:

> *Each column must be a minimum width of 300px and a maximum width of `1fr`.*

The `fr` unit consumes free space in the grid container. So if your container is 800px wide, the `fr` will factor in all that space.

Also, since `fr` consumes all free space, `justify-content`, which functions by distributing free space, is rendered useless.

Why not just remove the `1fr`?

```css
body {
  width: 800px;
  background: black;
}

.css {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 64px;
  grid-row-gap: 64px;
  background: red;
}

.grid div {
  background: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<div class="css grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Giving a fixed width to the columns works if there are enough elements to fill the first row. If I have enough room for 3 but only 2 elements to place they will be left aligned rather than centered.

Comment: Try adding `justify-items: center` to the grid container, as well.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything. Not in the fiddle or my actual use case.

Comment: I've got it, using auto-fit instead of auto-fill together with a fixed width for the elements creates the desired effect. 

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 300px);`